# setup django on docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I am new to docker and trying to steup my django project using docker first time.
I am following https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/
Below are the files and their conents that am using.
am using Ubuntu 16

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

requirements.txt

```
Django>=2.0,<3.0
psycopg2>=2.7,<3.0
```

I ran the below command

```
docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .
```

I have doubt in the below output:

```
.....:~/docker_practice$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
docker_practice_web   latest              be61fbfc4d9e        49 seconds ago       960MB
<none>                <none>              e73f8a4d68de        52 seconds ago       960MB
<none>                <none>              7b597f9f4615        About a minute ago   918MB
<none>                <none>              0eaf59a89be4        About a minute ago   918MB
<none>                <none>              cc42d26c3cfb        About a minute ago   918MB
<none>                <none>              ae64e2080658        About a minute ago   918MB
python                3                   02d2bb146b3b        11 days ago          918MB
mysql                 latest              b8fd9553f1f0        12 days ago          445MB


.......:~/docker_practice$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker_practice_web   latest              be61fbfc4d9e        52 seconds ago      960MB
python                3                   02d2bb146b3b        11 days ago         918MB
mysql                 latest              b8fd9553f1f0        12 days ago         445MB
```

When I run "docker images -a" It display 5 images with name as 
What this images are? 
where does it coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command `docker images -a` will show you also `intermediate images`, which is hidden in default using `docker images`

see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/)

Comment: I didn't make any changes in the code. Still just to give it a try I used the above suggested command but still "docker image -a" is showing the same output.

Comment: What is intermediate images ?

Comment: when you run docker build , there is many layers in the image created and removed through the build process , you cann see them when you run ` ---> Running in e81d9401db71
Removing intermediate container e81d9401db71`

Comment: see https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612